# Chrome onbeforeunload issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Trying to open the new site on close of the current tab/window, but the code is not getting executed neither alert or window.open.

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  alert("Am i hidden");
  window.open("https://www.google.com");
  return "Does chrome allow me to see the light.";
};
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on this so I can update my answer?

Comment: This hasn't been possible for years at this point.

Comment: To track the user activie time spent in our application, it can be tracked one logs off the application but when the user closes the browser window/tab is a issue then need to send a request from beforeunoald event to server to record the browser/tab close time.

Comment: Modern browsers prevent that to happen because it was abused.